# C++ enable_if template class method if it is std::vector<std::vector<Type>>

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I'm implementing a `flatten()` method for a struct that receives an `std::vector`.

I want the `flatten()` method to only be available if `MyStruct` is constructed with an `std::vector<std::vector<Type>>`, and not when it's constructed with `std::vector<Type>` (and `Type` is not an `std::vector`, of course).

It did manage to make it work, except for CLANG.
Depending on how I implement I get different errors.

I'd like to know the proper way of doing this with `enable_if`.

The signature of my struct should look similar to this:

```
template <typename Type>
struct MyStruct {

    ...

    // this should only exist if Type is an std::vector
    MyStruct<Type::value_type> flatten() {
        ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need enable_if for this? Plain ol' type deduction is for you:

```
template <typename T>
MyStruct<vector<T>> flatten(const MyStruct<vector<vector<T>>>& input) {
    // ...
}
```

---

EDIT: For your updated question, you really really probably want to use a nonmember here. It is a simpler API for your customers and given what this thing is doing, flatten probably doesn't need access to MyStruct's private bits, and if it doesn't need access to private bits it should be a non-member non-friend.

If for some reason you want to do this thing, you could write a trait for it using a free function, and then static_assert inside, similar to:

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/W0NG1VxX4fuia8kM
or
http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UJZ7qliuAqXLSW4b

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
std::false_type is_vector_of_vector_helper(const T&); // not defined
template <typename T>
std::true_type  is_vector_of_vector_helper(const std::vector<std::vector<T>>&);

template <typename T>
using is_vector_of_vector_t = decltype(is_vector_of_vector_helper(std::declval<T>()));

template <typename T>
struct MyStruct {
    MyStruct<typename T::value_type> flatten() const {
        static_assert(is_vector_of_vector_t<T>::value,
            "Flatten should only be called with MyStruct<vector<vector<T>>>");
        // impl

        return {};
    }
};
```

Comment: Always +1 for KISS solutions. :)

Comment: I don't want `flatten()` to receive an argument. It should access an internal value of `MyStruct`

Comment: If you want to make it a member then you're probably better off not trying to enable_if it and use static_assert inside instead.

Comment: Enable_if creates a terrible user experience because when type deduction fails, the thing comes out before overload resolution occurs, so the user gets a message of the form "flatten does not exist" rather than the message you probably want to show. It's an absolute last-possible resort when you have no other way to do something.

Comment: At this point I'm accepting anything that works, I don't really care about what message shows when the compiler fails. I updated my question to show you how I want to call my method. Could you update your answer to show how to use your suggestion of the `static_assert`?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz: If you were "accepting anything that works" you'd use a nonmember.

Comment: @BillyONeal failr enough, but by anything I mean any implementation, but maintaining that signature.

Comment: @BillyONeal It doesn't compile when you try to use with a 1 dimensional vector http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7g4lDA4B9ZKkKsnx

Comment: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4yl2P7blgRk3otgQ <-- Note that you actually *can't* use enable_if here -- enable_if SFINAE requires that flatten be a template and it is not.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance, but I don't understand what that means =/. Are you saying that what I want just ain't possible?

Comment: @Rodrigo: Yes. To enable_if something, it needs to be a template. (enable_if uses [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), which occurs as part of the template argument deduction process). In your example, flatten is not a template, so it can't be turned on or off like this. You can either do what my more recent link does (make flatten return void in this case and static_assert) or you can write a specialization that repeats all of MyStruct with flatten: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Rp5ere0uKobevE2Z

Comment: I tweaked your solution a little, but it worked! Thank you.